# What are some ways to display JSON data in Angular in a non-tabular format?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've hit a bit of a brick wall with an web application I'm writing and would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction from those of you who have more experience than me with Angular.

Here is some general information about the problem I'm facing:

I have JSON data in my controller's $scope. It's follows the following structure:

```
$scope.machines = [
{Name:"foo",type:"bar",onlineDt:"1"},
{Name:"fooda",type:"barda",onlineDt:"1"},
{Name:"fooda",type:"barda",onlineDt:"1"}]
```

On my index.html page I want a tile (using div and css to create the appearance of a tile) for each object in the $scope.data array. I want 8 objects displayed per row. I thought of using ngRepeat to display the objects, so I did the following as a test:

I created a method that populates a 2D array with rows of 8. Tested it out, it works great.

```
    $scope.grid = [];

    function assignMachinesToGrid() {
        $scope.grid = [];
        var arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.machines.length; i++) {
            if (arr.length < 9) {
                arr.push($scope.machines[i]);
            } else {
                $scope.grid.push(arr);
                arr = [];
            }
        }
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            $scope.grid.push(arr);
        }
    }
```

Then, in my view, I did the following.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div ng-repeat="row in $scope.grid">
            <div ng-repeat="tile in row">{{tile.Name}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It didn't work, but it was the best I could come up with. Any suggestions as to the proper way to display this information is welcome. Should I be using a 2 dimensional array? Is ng-repeat what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get rid of `$scope.` in `<div ng-repeat="row in $scope.grid">`. Actually, it should log an error in your console if you try this.

`<div ng-repeat="row in grid">` would be the right way to do it.

Comment: Agreed, you might need to add 'track by $index' depending on the version of angular

Comment: I just tried it as <div ng-repeat="row in grid">, worked like a charm. I swear I had tried that before posting.. but maybe I tried it BEFORE I caught a separate spelling error. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat as suggested by Alrazah also I would keep it in one array and use css to create the grid set their widths to 12.5% and float:left for example. The logic will be easier to follow dealing with one rather than 2 dimensions.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: I was suggesting creating an array and using css to create the grid. fix the css so grid[0]-grid[7] in the first row, grid[8]-grid[15] in the second... As you had already done the hard part my suggestion would not have helped you.